# Trying to animate a div when scrolling up a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to find out why `element2` does not shrink back to 300 px when I scroll back up the page. When I scroll down It grows but when I scroll up it doesn't shrink back. I'm also curious why sometimes the width toggles by itself when I'm in the scrolling area (like a delayed reaction).

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        var lastSCroll =  0;
        $(window).on("scroll", function(){
            var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(scrolled  > 470 && scrolled <1150){
                $(".element2").show("slow").css({"top" : scrolled + 30});
            }
            if( scrolled > 770 && scrolled < 1150 && scrolled > lastSCroll){
                $(".element2").animate({"width" : "500px"})
            }   
            if(scrolled > 770 && scrolled < 1150 && scrolled < lastSCroll){
                    $(".element2").animate({"width" : "300px"})
                }
                $(".display").html(scrolled + ": lastScroll--> " + lastSCroll)

            lastSCroll = scrolled ;
  });
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="element">Test</div>
<div class="element2">TEST 2</div>
<div class="display"></div>
<div class="firstCont"></div>
<div class="secondCont"></div>
<div class="thirdCont"></div>
<div class="fourthCont">4th</div>
```

CSS:

```
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .firstCont{
        height: 100vh;
        background: pink;
    }
    .display{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: .5em 1em;
        background: rgba(120,0,0,0.3);
        z-index: 5;
    }
    .secondCont{
        height: 100vh;
        background: hotpink;
    }
    .thirdCont{
        height: 100vh;
        background: seagreen;
    }
    .fourthCont{
        height: 100vh;
        background: skyblue;
    }
    .element{
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        background: blue;
        height: 200px;
        display: none;
    }
    .element2{
        background: gold;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `stop()` before `animate()` seems to do the trick. It prevents the animation queue building up and causing strange behaviour.
https://jsfiddle.net/o9o7ogsz/2/

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastSCroll = 0;
    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrolled > 470 && scrolled < 1150) {
            $(".element2").show("slow").css({
                "top": scrolled + 30
            });
        }
        if (scrolled > 770 && scrolled < 1150 && scrolled > lastSCroll) {
            $(".element2").stop().animate({
                "width": "500px"
            })
        }
        if (scrolled > 770 && scrolled < 1150 && scrolled < lastSCroll) {
            $(".element2").stop().animate({
                "width": "300px"
            })
        }
        $(".display").html(scrolled + ": lastScroll--> " + lastSCroll)

        lastSCroll = scrolled;
    });
});
```